# Syntax exception on trigger with multiple statements with MySQL and JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc, triggers, innodb

I am trying to create a **trigger that performs multiple operations in MySQL** 5.5.28 with InnoDB.

I have two tables, "test" and "test_watcher": changes to the first are recorded in the watcher table with the help of triggers. The last trigger needs to perform 2 operations on `DELETE`, it works in MySQL Workbench (with `DELIMITER`) but doesn't if I create it with JDBC.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `AD_test_FER` AFTER DELETE
  ON `test`
  FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
        -- if it's been inserted, modified and deleted but never synced, 
        -- the revision is NULL: no one needs to know about it
        DELETE FROM test_watcher WHERE pk = OLD.id AND revision IS NULL;

        -- if it has been synced already, we just update the flag
        UPDATE test_watcher SET flag = -1 WHERE pk = OLD.id;
      END;
```

I keep getting `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax`.

I know it works with `DELIMITER $$` in Workbench, but JDBC doesn't support it.

I've achieved it in PostgreSQL and would post the code if necessary.

Comment: Do you by any chance use the [connection property](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) `allowMultiQueries=true`. This might screw up things because it might simply split on `;`.

Comment: Very good point, I wasn't aware of it. I checked it and it seems to work. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior might be caused by the [connection property](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) `allowMultiQueries=true`. My guess is this property will make MySQL break up queries on the `;` as a query separator and then execute those as separate queries, essentially breaking your trigger creation code.

As you said in a - now deleted - answer that adding `allowMultiQueries=true` actually solved the problem (contrary to my expectiation), the problem might actually be the last `;` in your query. So another thing to check is if the problem goes away by removing the last `;` (in `END;`) in your script (and not using `allowMultiQueries=true`). Some database don't consider `;` to be valid at the end of a statement (as it is actually a delimiter to separate statements).

(this answer is based on my comment above)

Comment: Actually, it wasn't about this property, but there was a problem with the way the `;` were handled. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

If JDBC does not support delimiters (DELIMITER is a client command), then execute these two statements separately - one by one.

Comment: I also thought about this, but how could I do it? They are **inside the trigger** and should be executed at the same time.

Comment: No, I meant: DROP TRIGGER, then CREATE TRIGGER.

Comment: Okay, I updated my code to avoid nmisunderstandings. Please consider the DELETE and UPDATE statements inside the trigger creation.