# How to set up mysql multi-triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

How can i keep the below these triggers into a single trigger?

I have tried it, but i am not sure what mistake i am doing?

Below are my trigger's

1. ```
   create trigger Disminuir_Existencia1
   after insert
   on detalle 
   for each row 
   update producto set existencia =
                            existencia-new.Cantidad
                          where id_p=new.id_p
   ```
2. ```
   create trigger Aumentar_Existencia
   after insert
   on detalle
   for each row    

   update producto set existencia =if( new.activo = 0, producto.existencia +
    new.cantidad,producto.existencia)

   where new.id_P = producto.id_P
   ```
3. ```
   CREATE TRIGGER aumentar
   AFTER insert
   on detalle
   for each row

   update factura set total =
    ( 
        select producto.precio * new.cantidad
       from producto 
       where new.id_p=producto.id_p)

    where new.Folio= factura.folio;
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution in your situation may depend on what you have actually tried already and what were the results of your attempts.

For instance, it may turn out that you simply need to enclose your `UPDATE` statements in `BEGIN ... END` and that will be enough:

```
create trigger CombinedDetalleInsertTrigger
after insert
on detalle 
for each row 
begin
  update ... where id_p=new.id_p;

  update ... where new.id_P = producto.id_P;

  update ... where new.Folio= factura.folio;
end;
```

as [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921627/multiple-insert-update-statements-inside-trigger/1921657#1921657).

In many cases, however, you would also need to use the `DELIMITER` instruction:

```
delimiter $$

create trigger CombinedDetalleInsertTrigger
after insert
on detalle 
for each row 
begin
  update ... where id_p=new.id_p;

  update ... where new.id_P = producto.id_P;

  update ... where new.Folio= factura.folio;
end$$

delimiter ;
```

as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154158/mysql-how-do-i-use-delimiters-in-triggers/8154731#8154731).

Still, it may not always be possible to use `DELIMITER` as that is a client instruction [rather than a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017269/mysql-delimiter-syntax-error/9053823#9053823), and not all MySQL clients support it. In that case you can try following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623249/syntax-exception-on-trigger-with-multiple-statements-with-mysql-and-jdbc/14625872#14625872)'s suggestions: use the `allowMultiQueries=true` connection property or remove the final `;` (the one after the `end`).

Answer (score 0):

Mysql doesn't support the one trigger for all the operations like for example sql-server does.

You are doing it the way you have to in mysql.

If you want to have the code centralized, you can create a procedure and call the same procedure from the 3 different triggers with the NEW/OLD information and an identifier for the event (I/U/D).